# How do I delete a row from MySQL DB which is duplicated/

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have duplacated rows on my 'data' table (twice for each customer for each date).

and I want to remove one of them.

id - primary key

dat_id - customer id

dat_date - a date

running a query like this doesn't split both rows so I can see them clearly and i cant delete them from there:

```
SELECT
    dat_id, dat_date, COUNT(*)
FROM
    data
GROUP BY
    dat_id, dat_date
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

[image]

and clearly cant run `SELECT * FROM  data WHERE dat_date='2016-11-16' AND dat_id=769` on each and delete one of the results. 
[image]

I use PHPMyAdmin for comfort display.

What query can I run to display the results in an easy way to delete them or what query can I run to automatically delete the second duplicated data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a group by to delete replicates. Except the first row found:

```
DELETE FROM Mytable 
WHERE RowID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(RowID) 
                    FROM Mytable 
                    GROUP BY Col1,Col2,Col3)
```

Comment: What's RowID? 
I don't know what the row ID

Comment: Rowid is your register id,  the subquery is going to search if that id is not in all the registers. You have an id in every table , that is rowid

Comment: RowID doesn't exist in MySQL.  In this case, the solution will work if you substitute dat_id for RowID.  You will just want to add "and dat_date = '2016-11-16'" to the query. Actually, to both, otherwise you are going to be running a very long query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that all rows have multiple data, then do this:

```
SELECT row_id FROM tbl_name GROUP BY col, col, col
```

Once you get the row ids, then you can delete like this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE row_id IN (the_row_ids_gotten_above)
```

OR You write it in one query since you're using PHPMYADMIN

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE row_id IN (SELECT row_id FROM tbl_name GROUP BY user_id)
```

EDIT:
For those on that day (2016-11-16), do this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE date = '2016-11-16' AND row_id IN (SELECT row_id FROM tbl_name GROUP BY user_id)
```

Note: Do a backup before trying this just to be on the safe sound though it should work.

Comment: the thing is I don't know who's the row_id

Comment: `row_id` should be equivalent to your table's pseudo ID which I am guessing it's the `id` field in your table. So change `row_id` in my answer to `id`.

Comment: I edited my question with screen shots. just in case i wan't clear enough

Comment: Use of ID (row_id is an Oracleism) and "select min group by ..." will only work in the case that UUID or concatenated columns are not used as a primary key or that the data itself can be ordered properly.  The issue then becomes finding the proper key to do the "min/max" on, which can be problematic.

Comment: @RickSanchez You can copy and paste this:

`DELETE FROM data WHERE dat_date = '2016-11-16' AND id IN (SELECT id FROM data GROUP BY dat_id)`